# How to use .htaccess and .htpasswd for selective redirects & passwords

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

In my `/var/www/` directory I have many directories some like:

```
/var/www/impdata/
/var/www/data/
```

So can I achieve this:

When I go to: `www.websitename.com/data/` it should give a `404` error.

And when I do `www.websitename.com/data/welcome.php` it should work.

And when I do `www.websitename.com/impdata/` it should ask for username and password.

And when I do `www.websitename.com/impdata/welcome.php` it should work.

So how can i write my `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` to achieve this?

This is my current `.htaccess` file and it is in the `/var/www/` directory:

```
   Options -Indexes
   DirectoryIndex disabled

   <Directory /var/www/impdata>
     # All access controls and authentication are disabled
     Satisfy Any
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

My current `.htpasswd` file in the `/var/www/impdata/` directory:

```
 try:XYZXYZXYZXYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all .htaccess files are intended to have effect in the directory they're placed, so rather than having one in /var/www/ typically you would have two: one in each of /var/www/impdata/ and /var/www/data/

Or rather have no .htaccess files at all: my pet peeve, quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html) files:

> You should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

If I read your question right, when using using www.example.com/data/ you don't want to see the index.html or similar if it exists and you don't want to see a file listing either, but when requesting a specific file from that directory, you want to allow users to access that file.

```
<Directory /var/www/data>
   Options -Indexes         
   DirectoryIndex disabled
</Directory>
```

Adding authentication to /var/www/impdata with the otherwise the same options:

```
<Directory /var/www/impdata>
   Options -Indexes
   DirectoryIndex disabled
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "RESTRICTED AREA"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/impdata/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

You can disable certain files or directories within that password secured area from requiring authentication with the [`Satisfy Any`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require) directive:

```
<File /var/www/impdata/welcome.php>
   # All access controls and authentication are disabled
   Satisfy Any
   Allow from all
</File>
```

Comment: can i take this .htaccess one common  at root `Options -Indexes         
   DirectoryIndex disabled   'BUT SKIP /var/www/impdata/' ` and then this code in impadata `<Directory /var/www/impdata>
   Options -Indexes
   DirectoryIndex disabled
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "RESTRICTED AREA"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/impdata/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</Directory>`

Comment: When you remove the directory labels you can place the rest in a .htaccess file, yes.

Comment: i tried this `Options -Indexes
   DirectoryIndex disabled

   <Directory /var/www/impdata>
     # All access controls and authentication are disabled
     Satisfy Any
     Allow from all
  </Directory>` in root it gives me an 500 `Internal Server Error` to every directory and file

Comment: The Satisfy directive is only useful if access to a particular area is being restricted by both username/password (`Require valid-user`) and client host address (`Allow from all`). But check the errorlog for the exact reasons

Answer (score 3):

> So can I achieve this: When I go to: www.websitename.com/data/ it should give an 404 error.
>   And when do www.websitename.com/data/welcome.php it should work.

You can simply rewrite every request to a 404 not found status with an exception to welcome.php.
In the code below you will see that every rule gets rewritten tot a 404 status with the exception of welcome.php.

```
#.htaccess file of /var/www/data
RewriteEngine On

#Condition is that the requested URI is NOT data/welcome.php
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^data/welcome.php$
#Return 404 by default
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

> And when do www.websitename.com/impdata/ it should ask for username and password.
>   And when do www.websitename.com/impdata/welcome.php it should work.

As far as I know .htaccess files are per directory and therefor so is authentication. What you could however do is redirect all requests which do not equal welcome.php to a php script which then sends an authentication request. Or make a seperate directory, one with protected files and one without and redirect to these specific directories.
Here's an example where /impdata is not protected, but /impdata/auth is.
In this case /var/www/impdata/auth contains a .htaccess and .htpasswd requiring and /var/www/impdata/ contains a file handling the redirects.

```
#.htaccess of /var/www/impdata
RewriteEngine On

#Exception, if welcome.php is called, show it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/impdata/welcome.php$
#Make sure the path does not already exist out 
#of /impdata/auth/ as it would cause a redirect loop.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/impdata/auth/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ auth/$1 [L]
```

```
#.htaccess file of /var/www/impdata/auth
Options -Indexes
AuthType Basic
AuthName "RESTRICTED AREA"
AuthUserFile /var/www/impdata/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```